# How to Delete a Phabricator Diff

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I made a diff in Phabricator containing a config file with sensitive information. Usually I would be content with abandoning the diff, but I don't want anybody seeing my password (even after I change it)

I should have been more careful when making my commit but it has already been done.

Comment: Related question on phabricator https://secure.phabricator.com/Q278

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `./bin/remove` command:

```
NAME
  remove - remove objects

SYNOPSIS
  remove command [options]
      Administrative tool for destroying objects permanently.

WORKFLOWS

  destroy [options] object ...
  Permanently destroy objects.

  help [command]
  Show this help, or workflow help for command.

  log
  Show a log of permanently destroyed objects.


Use help command for a detailed command reference.
Use --show-standard-options to show additional options.
```

Comment: example: ./bin/remove destroy D1234